# Break array into 'tables' with ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv

I can't seem to get this down, right.

I have a big list of words in an array. I want these words to appear in 8 'tables', each 14 rows by 9 columns, with words running down each column of the table.

So I can get as far as `columns = words.each_slice(14)` and then later `tables = columns.each_slice(9)` but from there i'm not sure. I feel like I should make a hash and append the first n item of each column to an array, and then maybe join them with a tab delimiter.

My destination is a spreadsheet, so maybe outputting to CSV would make sense? I'm just not sure how to have it grouped into separate 'tables' (instead of just 9 columns with lots of rows and no separation) but maybe all it takes is a csv line with all blanks?

Anyway, any input or insight would be welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were on the right track. Here's a solution that writes in CSV format for lists whose length is a multiple of 14*9. You can also create a spreadsheet directly with the appropriate gem. I'll post an update which handles any length list shortly.

Note that I think `each_slice` requires you to include `Enumerable` for at least pre 2.0 Ruby versions.

```
(0...14*9*2).each_slice(14).collect.each_slice(9) {|table|
  table.transpose.each {|row|
    puts row.inspect.delete('[]')} ; puts}
```

If you need to pad your input `array` to a multiple of 14*9 so that the `transpose` works, you can use the following:

```
def print_csv(array)
  mod=array.length%(14*9)
  array = array+[nil]*(14*9-mod) if mod>0
  array.each_slice(14).collect.each_slice(9) {|table|
    table.transpose.each {|row|
      puts row.reject(&:nil?)*','} ; puts}
end
```

Comment: gah, naturally i'm off on the last array  ``element size differs (8 should be 14)``

Comment: @meesterfox - Is everything ok now with the updated version's ability to handle arbitrary length? I ask in part because you haven't upvoted this and I was wondering if there was something lacking.

Comment: I don't think fiddling with the result of `inspect` is a valid technique. The string returned by `inspect` isn't specified, and so shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: @Borodin - You're absolutely right. Thanks for the feedback. If there were a way to share points with you, I would. I updated it.

Comment: Peter thanks for the update. did upvote and mark as solution.

Comment: @meesterfox - Oh, sorry! I saw the accept earlier, but didn't realize the upvote was cancelled by a downvote vote-tally-wise. Keep forgetting about that phenomenon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you ask

You don't say anything about the output format you want, so I've just surrounded each word with quotes, joined them with commas and put a blank line between tables.

My "words" are just the numbers 1 to 200.

```
words = (1 .. 200).map { |v| '%03d' % v }

words.each_slice(14).each_slice(9) do |table|
  (0 ... table[0].size).each do |i|
    row = table.map { |column| column[i] }
    row.pop if row[-1].nil?
    puts row.map { |cell| %<"#{cell}"> }.join ','
  end
  puts ''
end
```

**output**

```
"001","015","029","043","057","071","085","099","113"
"002","016","030","044","058","072","086","100","114"
"003","017","031","045","059","073","087","101","115"
"004","018","032","046","060","074","088","102","116"
"005","019","033","047","061","075","089","103","117"
"006","020","034","048","062","076","090","104","118"
"007","021","035","049","063","077","091","105","119"
"008","022","036","050","064","078","092","106","120"
"009","023","037","051","065","079","093","107","121"
"010","024","038","052","066","080","094","108","122"
"011","025","039","053","067","081","095","109","123"
"012","026","040","054","068","082","096","110","124"
"013","027","041","055","069","083","097","111","125"
"014","028","042","056","070","084","098","112","126"

"127","141","155","169","183","197"
"128","142","156","170","184","198"
"129","143","157","171","185","199"
"130","144","158","172","186","200"
"131","145","159","173","187"
"132","146","160","174","188"
"133","147","161","175","189"
"134","148","162","176","190"
"135","149","163","177","191"
"136","150","164","178","192"
"137","151","165","179","193"
"138","152","166","180","194"
"139","153","167","181","195"
"140","154","168","182","196"
```